# \pdfmarkupcomment in standalone

Tags: pdfcomment

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment[color=red,markup=StrikeOut]{A little Test!}{Why is this repeated? This is a StrikeOut markup annotation} 
\end{document}
```

The `pdfmarkupcomment` is not shown. With `\documentclass{article}` it is. How can I make use of `pdfmarkupcomment` in standalone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdfcomment use soulpos to calculate the size of the annotation. soulpos writes some values with `\AtEndDocument` to an external file, but with standalone the `\AtEndDocument` is not executed (it would if you would use multi, but then the page size is wrong).

You can execute the needed code manually

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[color=red,markup=StrikeOut]{A little Test!}{Why is this repeated? This is a StrikeOut markup annotation}%

\makeatletter
\closeout\ulp@out
  \closein\ulp@in
  \write\@auxout{\string\ulp@afterend}%
  \def\ulp@afterend{%
    \ulp@cnt\z@
    \message{* soulpos - computing points - it may take a few seconds *}%
    \immediate\openout\ulp@out=\jobname.upb\relax
    \begingroup
      \makeatletter
      \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.upa}{}{}%
    \endgroup
    \immediate\closeout\ulp@out}%
\makeatother    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mhm weird, for me that does not work

Comment: i.e. it does not change a thing

Comment: it seems to "work" if I call pdflatex on a documentclass article and change it afterwards to standalone and recall pdflatex (without deleting the ^*tex files); that seems unintended; do you get an annotated pdf with directly setting documentclass to standalone??

Comment: hm, right it was a side effect. I will adapt the answer.

Comment: thanks again frau fischer =)