# Conflict between package pdfcomment and the book class

Tags: books, pdfcomment

I have a small file

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

The \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{yellow mark}{Highlight}.

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

that it is supposed to show the yellow highlight on the third run of LaTeX (pdf-, xe- or lua-), but it never does, no matter how many times it is run.

If you go there and comment the line:

```
%\backmatter
```

It does, properly, display the highlight after the third run.

What could possibly be the conflict between the command `\backmatter` and the `pdfcomment` package? Any ways to avoid it?

Obs. 1: There is a message to the effect that `soulutf8` is an obsolete package and recommending to load the `soul` package directly. Loading it earlier, does get rid of the message, but the behaviour is exactly the same.

Obs.2: If you want to repeate the sequence (of 6 runs) to exhibit the problem, you have to uncomment the line in the file as well as remove the file `*.upb` that, if left over will keep showing the highlight.

Comment: well it is a bug in soulpos. It uses \write in \AtEndDocument to finish some stuff, but after a \clearpage this is lost. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593585/2388 for a similar problem.

Comment: @JavierBezos Javier, is this somewhat fixable?

Comment: I don't think that Javier can see this ping. Better open an issue at the soulpos github.